# Best way to calculate player places in php

Tags: php

I have points assigned to each player like this:

player1 = 20 , player2 = 30, player3 = 50, player4 = 10, player5 = 25 and so on.

and these points change as they score more points. What i am trying to do is if player2 looks at his page he should see which player of all has highest score, where he is in all players and who has the lowest score? What is the best way to do this in php? So it will show something like this:

```
Highest Scorer                 Player2                              Lowest Score
    player3       you are 2nd highest out of 5 players               player4
```

Comment: So you don't need to find the median.

Comment: Not exactly the median... where does player2 stands.

Comment: if yes, use ORDER BY score, if not, use PHP's [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) functions?

Comment: Not ever sort is needed. Just iterate through the users two times. Smaller complexity also.

Comment: @George - what do you mean by iterate through users two times? Can you show in code??

Comment: and it is in an array the users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// $users is an array in the form: playerID => score
$minScore = 0; $minScoreUser;
$maxScore = -1; $maxScoreUser;
$thisScore; $thisPlayer;
foreach ($users as $player => $score)
{
   if ( $player == $queryPlayer )
   {
       $thisScore = $score;
       $thisPlayer = $player;
   }
   if ( $maxScore < 0 || $score > $maxScore )
   {
       $maxScore = $score;
       $maxScorePlayer = $player;
   }
   if ( $score < $minScore )
   {
       $minScore = $score;
       $minScorePlayer = $player;
   }
}

$higherCount = 0;
foreach ($users as $player => $score)
    if ( $score > $thisScore ) $higherCount++;
```

$minScore and $minScorePlayer is the lowest player

$maxScore and $maxScorePlayer is the highest player

$thisScore and $thisPlayer is the player you are interested in

$higherCount is the number of players with higher score than your player

The above has a complexity of O(n)

The sorting solution has a complexity of O(n * logn )

Comment: I agree with the sorting algorythm to be more complex, but it is more straight forward than looking like this. Complexity will be noticeable when the set of date will be very large.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything bad about the sorting solution. I'm just mentioning the complexity also. In fact I myself would probably choose the sorting solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use php uasort function, and then you can have place in which your player stands in. Taken from php.net:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
}
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

the array will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [d] => -9
    [h] => -4
    [c] => -1
    [e] => 2
    [g] => 3
    [a] => 4
    [f] => 5
    [b] => 8
)
```

Then you can use which place it stands in:

```
function key_offset(&$array, $searchKey){
    if(is_array($array) && array_key_exists($searchKey, $array)){
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if($searchKey == $key){
                return $counter;
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now it would look like this:

```
// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');

// Return index of the place in which your player is now.
$index = key_offset($array, "PlayerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the existing answers are sufficient.

If you're just trying to find everyone's score and rank at once, it's easy: just do

```
SELECT * FROM TableOfScores ORDER BY score
```

That'll give you the scores in order, and you can increment a counter each time you iterate to get their rank. However, I think what you want is to simply show one person's screen, judging by your "You are the 2nd highest" message. In that case, it's even simpler because you certainly don't need to sort the whole list just to get one person's rank.

Note that you should build an index on score. This will take up a bit of time when you're inserting/deleting player scores, but it will make the this query run MUCH faster.

To find the number of total tests taken just do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalScores FROM TableOfScores
```

To find the place of the current user, do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CurrentPersonsRank FROM TableOfScores WHERE score <= $currentPersonScore
```

I hope this helps.